# calculate 5 year average of panel data with factors kept

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a panel data set that may look like

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(
  year = rep(2011:2020,5),
  county = rep(c("a","b",'c','d','e'), each=10),
  state = rep(c("A","B",'C','D','E'), each=10),
  country = rep(c("AA","BB",'CC','DD','EE'), each=10),
  var1 = runif(50, 0, 50),
  var2 = runif(50, 50, 100)
)
```

I want to transform the panel data set to 5 year averages of the counties by

```
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(period = cut(df$year, seq(2011, 2021, by = 5),right = F)) %>% 
  group_by(county, period) %>% 
  summarise_all(mean)
```

The data set looks like

```
   county period       year state country  var1  var2
   <chr>  <fct>       <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 a      [2011,2016)  2013    NA      NA  33.1  69.7
 2 a      [2016,2021)  2018    NA      NA  24.7  73.6
 3 b      [2011,2016)  2013    NA      NA  27.6  72.3
 4 b      [2016,2021)  2018    NA      NA  24.7  83.1
 5 c      [2011,2016)  2013    NA      NA  38.7  75.7
 6 c      [2016,2021)  2018    NA      NA  22.8  66.8
 7 d      [2011,2016)  2013    NA      NA  33.8  72.2
 8 d      [2016,2021)  2018    NA      NA  20.0  83.7
 9 e      [2011,2016)  2013    NA      NA  14.9  71.0
10 e      [2016,2021)  2018    NA      NA  19.6  70.4
```

The warming messages are, for example

```
In mean.default(state) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

Is there a smart way (not by merging as actually, I have a lot of character columns) to keep the time-invariant character of each county after the transformation?
What I desire is

```
   county period       year state country  var1  var2
   <chr>  <fct>       <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 a      [2011,2016)  2013    A      AA  33.1  69.7
 2 a      [2016,2021)  2018    A      AA  24.7  73.6
 3 b      [2011,2016)  2013    B      BB  27.6  72.3
 4 b      [2016,2021)  2018    B      BB  24.7  83.1
 5 c      [2011,2016)  2013    C      CC  38.7  75.7
 6 c      [2016,2021)  2018    C      CC  22.8  66.8
 7 d      [2011,2016)  2013    D      DD  33.8  72.2
 8 d      [2016,2021)  2018    D      DD  20.0  83.7
 9 e      [2011,2016)  2013    E      EE  14.9  71.0
10 e      [2016,2021)  2018    E      EE  19.6  70.4
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The warnning results from that `summarise_all(mean)` calculates averages not only on `var1` & `var2` but on `state` & `country`. If you want to keep `state` and `country` as grouping columns, you should put them into `group_by()`:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(county, state, country,
           period = cut(year, seq(2011, 2021, by = 5), right = FALSE)) %>%
  summarise_all(mean) %>%
  ungroup()

# # A tibble: 10 × 7
#    county state country period       year  var1  var2
#    <chr>  <chr> <chr>   <fct>       <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#  1 a      A     AA      [2011,2016)  2013  33.1  69.7
#  2 a      A     AA      [2016,2021)  2018  24.7  73.6
#  3 b      B     BB      [2011,2016)  2013  27.6  72.3
#  4 b      B     BB      [2016,2021)  2018  24.7  83.1
#  5 c      C     CC      [2011,2016)  2013  38.7  75.7
#  6 c      C     CC      [2016,2021)  2018  22.8  66.8
#  7 d      D     DD      [2011,2016)  2013  33.8  72.2
#  8 d      D     DD      [2016,2021)  2018  20.0  83.7
#  9 e      E     EE      [2011,2016)  2013  14.9  71.0
# 10 e      E     EE      [2016,2021)  2018  19.6  70.4
```

---

If the grouping columns are simply `county` and `period`, and other categorical variables are unique in each group, you could keep them by just leaving the first values with `first()` while doing `summarise()`.

```r
df %>%
  group_by(county,
           period = cut(year, seq(2011, 2021, by = 5), right = FALSE)) %>%
  summarise(across(!where(is.numeric), first),
            across( where(is.numeric), mean)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Comment: Thank you again. I have thought of this. So mostly I still need to 'list' all my time-invariant columns in a way. Is it possible to do it in a tidy/neat way if I have a lot of them? My actual dataset have ~70 columns and ~10 are characters I wish to keep?

Comment: @xxx Yes, see my update!

Comment: Thank you! across() is the new thing I learnt here!